# Multiple begin rescue block

Tags: ruby, error-handling, coding-style

There is a code in which every line can cause an exception and I want to continue my execution even if an error occurred in any of the lines of code

I will implement this in the below-mentioned way

```
begin
   code that might throw an exception
rescue
   logger
end

begin
   code that might throw an exception
rescue
   logger
end

begin
   code that might throw an exception
rescue
   logger
end

begin
   code that might throw an exception
rescue
   logger
end
```

is there any better way to handle this type of error handling if yes please explain how can I write better code

Comment: the code that might throw an exception is some private function, honebadger notification, NewRelic notification

Comment: Exceptions bubble up. Just wrap all your code in a single begin/rescue. What you're doing makes absolutely no sense, especially as there's a huge difference between expected errors and true exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

> every line can cause an exception

> please explain how can I write better code

You can write better code by not designing it in such a way that every line can raise an exception. Especially this idea that the code should "plough on ahead, regardless of any trail of errors are left in its wake".

At an extreme, you code could contain all sorts of spelling mistakes / invalid method calls / whatever, and your proposed design would attempt to continue executing the remainder of the code, regardless of how broken it is.

However, I cannot really give concrete advice on how to do this, without seeing some actual code.

Comment: every line is sending error info using some logger or some slack or Email that's why there might be the case that an exception occurs otherwise I totally agree with your comment

Comment: Why does sending information to a logger/slack/email possibly result in an **EXCEPTION** being raised?? (Especially an exception that you can safely ignore!!) This is a poor design, and I reiterate the above advice.

Comment: okay i will look into it so that i can better design my code thanks